# How to change background color on ion-toggle Angular-ionic3

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic3, toggle

i want to change background color when i select toggle, right now the bacground color is white, and i want to change it to grey.
here is my ion-toggle right now
[image]
and this is what i want
[image]

this is my .html code

```
 <ion-item>
     <ion-label no-padding>Allows phone calls?</ion-label>
     <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="lead.isAllowCall" (ionChange)="change()" [disabled]="lead.oppDisable"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

and this is my .scss code

```
    ion-toggle {
    --background: grey;
    --background-checked: #303E9F;
  
    --handle-background: #303E9F;
    --handle-background-checked: #grey;
  }
```

i tried that code, but its not working perfectly, can u guys help me how to fix it?